# UPDATE STATEMENT with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause

I want to update table `sheet` and set column value of `hproject` to 'yes' where `customer` having `hproject`='yes'

```
UPDATE `sheet` SET `hproject` =  'yes' WHERE (
SELECT `customer`
FROM `sheet`
WHERE `hproject` =  'yes'
)
```

Above query is not working, i'll be grateful for any help or guidance.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that :

```
  UPDATE `sheet` SET `hproject` =  'yes' WHERE `customer` in (
  select * from(
  SELECT `customer`
  FROM `sheet`
  WHERE `hproject` =  'yes'
 )t
 )
```